# preg_match_all() returns only the last matches from a single row, but all matches from a multi-row string

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I try to find all occurrences of a substring in text, using the [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function:

```
<?php
    $str = '<p>this <a href="https://api.slack.com/apps/" target="_blank">link</a> and <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">link 2</a></p>';

    $reg = '/<a.*href="([^"]+)"[^>]+>(.+)<\/a>/';

    preg_match_all($reg, $str, $m);

    print_r($m);
```

But the above code returns only the last link: [run PHP online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/77da0b585127809df1880d06d224716c/)

When I split the source text into rows, the same code returns all matches:

```
<?php
    $str = '<p>this <a href="https://api.slack.com/apps/" target="_blank">link</a> and
    the <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">link 2</a></p>';

    $reg = '/<a.*href="([^"]+)"[^>]+>(.+)<\/a>/';

    preg_match_all($reg, $str, $m);

    print_r($m);
```

[PHP sandbox here](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/269cb5b03948d8450be6de3c5975f9ba/)

Comment: Because you used `>.+</a>` in your regex, so `</a>...<a...` satisfied `.+`. If you look at `$m[0]` in first situation, you would notice that the (almost) whole line is matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your regular expression. You can limit the characters:

```
/<a\s*href="([^"]+)"[^>]+>([^<]+)<\/a>/
```

Or use lazy matching:

```
/<a.*?href="([^"]+)"[^>]+>(.+?)<\/a>/
```